# Plotting two disconnnected surfaces simultaneously in matlab

Tags: matlab, animation, matlab-figure

I'm running a for loop which currently animates `surf` plots using columns 1:k (`for k=1:301`) of 3 different matrices (representing x, y, and z) of dimension 21 x 602. However, simultaneously I want to surf plot columns `for 302:k+301`, so that in essence, I get the animations of two flux tubes at the same time.

Currently, I have:

```
p = surf(nan(21,602), nan(21,602), nan(21,602));
for k = 1:301
     % Update all of the plot objects at once
     set(p, 'XData', x(:, 1:k), ...
            'YData', y(:, 1:k), ...
            'ZData', z(:, 1:k),'facecolor', Colour, 'edgecolor',EdgeColour,...
    'facelighting','gouraud')
drawnow
end
```

But obviously, this is only plotting the first animation as it's currently written. How can this be adapted to also plot the other columns required (and therefore the other animation) at the same time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
p1 = surf([0 0 ;0 0]);
hold all
p2 = surf([0 0 ;0 0]);
for k = 1:301
    % Update all of the plot objects at once
    set(p1, 'XData', x(:,1:k), ...
        'YData', y(:,1:k), ...
        'ZData', z(:,1:k),'facecolor', Colour, 'edgecolor',EdgeColour,...
        'facelighting','gouraud')
    set(p2, 'XData', a(:,1:k), ...
        'YData', b(:,1:k), ...
        'ZData', c(:,1:k),'facecolor', Colour, 'edgecolor',EdgeColour,...
        'facelighting','gouraud')
    drawnow
end
hold off
```

`x,y,z` is the data for one helix, and `a,b,c` is the data for the other helix.
You need to create two different axes (`p1` and `p2`) so `surf` wan't connect the data altogether

Hope it answers the question :)

Comment: For some reason that's also running through as an error!!

Comment: Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in tuba (line 79)
     set(p, 'XData', x(:, [1:k N/2:N/2+k]), ...

Comment: Oh wait I think I've taken something out of the code which made x,y and z smaller. I shall change them back and run again

Comment: I also edited it now so it takes `x(:, [1:k N/2+1:N/2+k])`, for not duplicating the `N/2` element in `x` (or `y` or `z`)

Comment: It does run now, but it forms a deformed single shape, rather than two separate tubes as required!!

Comment: This is just an example on arbitrary data, you can plug in your `x,y,z` variables and see if it works for you ;)

Comment: Sorry I should've been more clearer!! I did try it with my data and the deformed shape was formed. The helical flux tube looks the same as normal, but the vertical flux tube through the centre of it has become twisted and mangled!!

Comment: Can you send me your data so I can see what you meen?

Comment: Yes sure, how do I do that? The data is created via a function so it is not actually raw data. The master script calls in 4 other function so I'd have to send you them all for the animation to run, but that's not an issue!!

Comment: Just send the .m files as a dropbox/google drive or any other link, so I can download them

Comment: All the relevant scripts are in this folder I believe https://www.dropbox.com/sh/u045qivsj9irkht/AACHRckbIcJQZzFexZjEBq32a?dl=0 the master script is helix, but all of the code for the drawing is in tuba.m

Comment: Sorry I've been at work all day. It worked amazingly thanks, I shall mark it as an answer now!